# Does Spring Form Backing support takes null as a value of an entity

Tags: ajax, spring, model-view-controller

I have an entity **User[userid, name , age]**

Now from jsp I am hitting ajax like this:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/user/saveUser.htm",
            data: "userid=" + userid+ "&name=" + name + "&age=" + age,
success: function (response) {
alert("success");
}
```

And my controller is:

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = {"saveUser"}, method = {RequestMethod.POST})
    public String submitProblem(HttpServletRequest req, User user) 

{
     //backend codes
}
```

My question is when I am sending name="ABC" , age="24" and **id=32;**
everything is fine.
But  "**The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.**" response comes if I am sending **id=null**.

Please help me to know the issue.

Comment: How does user look like?

Comment: User has 3 parameters 
@ Entity
@ Table(name = "user")
public class User
        implements Serializable {

    @ Id
    @ GeneratedValue
    @ Basic(optional = false)
    @ Column(name = "userid")
    private Integer userid;
    @ Basic(optional = false)
    @ Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @ Basic(optional = false)
    @ Column(name = "age")
    private String age;

Answer (score 0):

try to use json data in your ajax request first you can use

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/user/saveUser.htm",
            data: {'userid': userid, 'name': name, 'age' : age},
success: function (response) {
alert("success");
}
```

and try to use corectly with spring i cant help you ive never use spring also your error is type of id

if you convert your id on string maybe this will work because your age work try to do

```
userid = userid.toString();
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/user/saveUser.htm",
            data: "userid=" + userid+ "&name=" + name + "&age=" + age,
success: function (response) {
alert("success");
}
```